# Does construction fail if some other instantiation fails inside the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a constructor like this

```
    ClassA::ClassA(void)
    {
       pImplClassA = new (std::nothrow) pImplClassA();
       if (pImplClassA == null)
       {
         return;
       }
    }
    ClassA::SomeFunc()
    {
      pImplClassA->SomeFunc();
    }
```

My question is, should pClassB fails, will classA instance also be null or it would be already instantiated when I have done this.

```
  ClassA* pClassA = new ClassA()
    pClassA->SomeFunc();
```

Shouldn't pClassA be null because constructor has failed. if not I woul be still be able to call ClassA::SomeFunc() and it will crash there as it is not instantiated.

Would pClassA be null or not?
Thanks

Comment: Why not test it and see for yourself?

Comment: In C++, there's no such concept as an "instance being null". Nor can "pClassB fail"; it's just a pointer. The question makes no sense.

Comment: Whenever I have questions like yours, I go somewhere like http://ideone.com/ and just check what happens.

Comment: @loki2302: With undefined behavior lurking around every corner, that's not a very useful strategy in C++.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: What? Undefined behavior? This guy says "fails" instead of "throws", he's probably reading his first C++ book.

Comment: @loki2302: Are you asking me what undefined behavior is? [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). For the second, he didn't say "throws", because he obviously didn't mean "throws".  In fact, he specifically requested it *not* throw with `std::nothrow`.  If he's on his first C++ book, that's all the more reason he shouldn't simply rely on compiling his program and checking the output in order to answer his questions about behavior.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: I'm not asking you what UB is, I'm just saying TS is probably not yet ready for all this "The Standard" stuff. I'm a firm believer that UB is not the first thing one should know when learning C++.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I dont understand. throws means some exception.does fail mean more graceful exit? I am sorry but I am confused now? fail means som UB, which is what exception is. right?

Comment: I gave no::throw because I specificaly want it to give null and not bad_alloc.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by fail? If `ClassB`'s constructor throws an exception, since you're not catching it in `ClassA`'s constructor, it's as if `ClassA`'s constructor would throw an exception, so no, the object wouldn't be created and there would be no `pClassA` to speak of.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am handling null for pClassB. What happens now?

Comment: @V.KSingh if you handle the exception inside the constructor, the object will be created. Of course. `pClassA` will not be null, it will point to a valid object.

Comment: but if pClassA is not null then what is the use of this constructor. I mean Imagine that I have some pImpl instantiation(pClassB is pImpl for instance). if pClassA is valid then doesnt it defeat the purpose of constructor. I mean if pClass A is valid, what is the use, I will not be able to use this pImpl.

Comment: @V.KSingh of course there's no use to it, that's why you don't catch the exception. :)